# How to retrieve the user's name and email address from a Google OAuth callback?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-oauth

I am trying to retrieve the signed in user's name and email address once they have signed in via Google. Here is my code:

```
@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)
    
    if not session["state"] == request.args["state"]:
        abort(500)  # State does not match!
    credentials = flow.credentials
    request_session = requests.session()
    cached_session = cachecontrol.CacheControl(request_session)
    token_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request(session=cached_session)
    id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
        id_token=credentials._id_token,
        request=token_request,
        audience=oauth_client_id
    )
    session["google_id"] = id_info.get("sub")
    session["name"] = id_info.get("name")
    session["email"] = id_info.get("email")
    return redirect("/")
```

Nothing displays when I store `session["name"] = id_info.get("name")` or `session["email"] = id_info.get("email")` in a variable and print this to console?

Comment: Go though the people api https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo it's not a really good way to deal with that, because a user can have several email addresses.

Comment: This the options we have.  there is no good option.